# What is the name of attached animation, when clicked on center button I want to pop up other buttons around it. how can I achieve in html and CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, button

[image]

I want to perform the animation on a web page when clicking the central button I want other buttons to pop up and stay unless I click the central plus button again to close the hovering buttons.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a same Icon Drawer Animation.

```js
const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");
let isOpen = false;
function showAndHide() {
  if (!isOpen) {
    icons[0].style["transform"] = "translate(0px,0px)";
    icons[1].style["transform"] = "translate(-110px,0px)";
    icons[2].style["transform"] = "translate(-80px,-80px)";
    icons[3].style["transform"] = "translate(0px,-110px)";
    icons[4].style["transform"] = "translate(80px,-80px)";
    icons[5].style["transform"] = "translate(110px,0px)";
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
      icons[i].style["transform"] = `translate(0,0)`;
    }
  }
  isOpen = !isOpen;
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.icon {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -5;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 0.6s;
}

#icon1 {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #d07f65;
}

#icon2 {
  background-color: #fed4ae;
}

#icon3 {
  background-color: #86eb83;
}

#icon4 {
  background-color: #a6eaef;
}

#icon5 {
  background-color: #d1b8d1;
}

#icon6 {
  background-color: #f9b4be;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-5A8nwdMOWrSz20fDsjczgUidUBR8liPYU+WymTZP1lmY9G6Oc7HlZv156XqnsgNUzTyMefFTcsFH/tnJE/+xBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-SfTiTlX6kk+qitfevl/7LibUOeJWlt9rbyDn92a1DqWOw9vWG2MFoays0sgObmWazO5BQPiFucnnEAjpAB+/Sw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="icon" id="icon1" onclick="showAndHide()"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
<div class="icon" id="icon2"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
<div class="icon" id="icon3"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
<div class="icon" id="icon4"><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
<div class="icon" id="icon5"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
<div class="icon" id="icon6"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```